# How to access imported items

Tags: go

With following project structure

```
D:\src\go\my-app
 + internal\
 |  + utils.go
 + main.go
 + go.mod
```

with following file contents:

`internal\utils.go`:

```
package internal

func GetText() string {
    return "hello world"
}
```

`main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "example.com/my_app/internal"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(GetText())
}
```

`go.mod`:

```
module example.com/my_app

go 1.17
```

I'm getting following compilation error when running from the directory:

```
D:\src\go\my-app>go build
# example.com/my_app
.\main.go:5:2: imported and not used: "example.com/my_app/internal"
.\main.go:9:14: undefined: GetText
```

Any idea, what could be wrong?

PS: This question is reproducible and not caused by a typo, but by a wrong assumption (in other programming languages the imported items are accessed by their name).

Comment: Duplicate of "[rand package error in Go](//stackoverflow.com/q/8231573/90527)", "[Package imports, cannot use struct from imported package](//stackoverflow.com/q/25143626/90527)" and likely others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem is quite clear:

- You import `example.com/my_app/internal` but you don't use it. If you used it, there'd be `internal.<something>` somewhere in your main.
- `GetText()` does not exist: there is no `GetText()` function in your main package.

Solution:

Replace `GetText()` by `internal.GetText()`. Now `example.com/my_app/internal` is used and `GetText()` is found in this package.

Comment: Note that you can also use `. "example.com/my_app/internal"` in your package import if you don't want the `internal` package to be used as scoped, this is equivalent of `using namespace` in C++ for instance. This is not advised though because of the risks for name conflicts.